# Why not train RNN with x=data[0:n] and y=data[n+1] (but instead x=data[0:n] and y=data[1:n+1])?

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, transformer-model

This is a general and I think very basic/elementary question about how to set up recurrent neural networks. For the sake of it, let's assume we're training an autoregressive language model that tries to predict the next character in some text.

When I look at existing implementations that train an RNN, what I usually find is that the data fed to these RNNs are snippets of a certain length where the input and output are of the same shape, but shifted relative to each other by one sample (such that the predictor x is data[0:n] and the predictee y is data[1:n+1]).
At the end of such an RNN, we'd usually find some sort of mapping (+softmax) from the hidden state h_t to the number of classes (here: characters). Usually, this seems to produce a class label for each of the input time samples, i.e., we get a class label prediction for each output sample. In other words, we predict y[0] from predictor[0] using the hidden state after it has seen x[0] (h_t=0), we predict y[1] from x[1] using (h_t=1), and so on and so forth.

I find this surprising, because I thought the whole point of RNNs was to "build up" / "develop" a hidden state over a certain amount of time. I.e., in a case as described above, I would expect that we should only generate a single prediction for data[n+1] (i.e. y[n]), using h_t=n (where h is thus integrating and thus exploiting the entire history length as defined by the data loader).
If a hidden state is initiated randomly, and then only sees 1 single sample of data, I would naively assume it should perform a lot worse vs when it has seen n data points. If the mapping from hidden state to output is trained with such suboptimal "premature" states, shouldn't it converge on some compromise between compensating for the premature states and ideally exploiting information in a "mature" hidden state?

However, usually, when I try to set an RNN up in the way I thought it should make more sense, it doesn't work as well (I reach worse validation losses). This could be for several reasons (given that I am not providing my code), but can someone maybe enlighten me if there is a good theoretical motivation why RNNs (and transformers) aren't usually fed with pairs of predictor=data[0:n] and predictee=data[n+1]?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect explanation, and I suggest you do some reading on RNNs and their inner workings, but I'm going to give it a shot at explaining.

The point of the RNN is to be able to predict the next output at every timepoint, which is how it builds up its state. By taking the joint probability distribution, conditioned on prior outputs, you want to learn to predict `y_t` by `(P(y_t | y_(t-1), y_(t-2), ...)`. If all you do is feed in an entire timeseries to predict a final output value, then you might as well use a fully connected layer.

Another way to think about it, is that the model is training in the way you suggest but several times over, until the length of the sequence is `n`.

First, the model predicts the first word `t_1` based on some input `t_0`. `t_1` is then added to the input, and `t_0` and `t_1` are used to predict `t_2`. We repeat this process until we predict the final word `t_n`. So we get a growing sequence like below:

```
t_0           -> t_1
t_0, t_1      -> t_2
t_0, t_1, t_2 -> t_3
...
```

Obviously this would be quite computationally expensive since we are re-computing the growing sequence `n` times, and also we have no record of how we computed the prior outputs. So we carry with us a state parameter. This parameter encodes the computations that have taken place up until timepoint `t`. So the above chain of computations instead becomes

```
s = 0
s_0, t_0  ->  s_1, t_1
s_1, t_1  ->  s_2, t_2
s_2, t_2  ->  s_3, t_3
...
```

> If a hidden state is initiated randomly, and then only sees 1 single sample of data, I would naively assume it should perform a lot worse vs when it has seen n data points

This would indeed be the case if all you provide your model is a randomized hidden state and some input, lets say the letter `a`. Then your model will just output some random value. Similarly, if you always initialize your hidden state to 0 then your model will act as a fancy look up table and simply chose what ever value most commonly follows `a` in your training data.

However, generally for language models you are conditioning/prompting your model on some input already. eg. in machine translation that might be a sentence, in image caption generation it would be encoded image features.

This brings us back to the idea that we are actually predicting `data[n+1]` from `data[0:n]` as you suggest. And then repeatedly appending the output onto the input to predict the next output.

So why doesn't your way of training work? I think that is because you are not allowing the model to learn the entire joint probability space. You are simply saying that if I have this sequence `n` I want to predict his singular output `y`, rather than allowing the model to learn the chain of predictions that eventually lead to `y`.

Comment: Thx! 1) The "feed ts, predict outputvalue -> use fc" I find surprising. Isn't it supposed to be tough to get the long-range dependencies, and you'll just have exploding number of params with fc?
2) Your description of "growing sequence": Sounds like you mean that the prediction "t_1_hat" is used to predict t_2?
3) if I am not mistaken, standard RNN code indeed re-initialises hidden state anew for each training sample 4) feeding entire sequence of n items imo should be what allows estimating the joint probability space. Don't need the chain of predictions, just need an evolving hidden state.